# Why does innerHTML not change src of an image?

Tags: javascript, image, element

I have to set one src to an image object. Then I change it.

But if I add something to the element (content of element), such as

```
meaning.innerHTML += ")";
```

(where meaning is parent element of image), then if change the src of object it won't affect the document.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/WcnCB/3/

Could you explain me why it happens, and how to fix it?

Comment: just when i thought i knew every reason to never use `innerHTML`, here's another :P

Comment: @jbabey It's classic mistake anyone learns when they try to do real work with it... my first code freezed the browser for 6 minutes cos of += innerHTML in a loop of 1000 items. It was instant with a pre concatenated string. :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`meaning.innerHTML += ')';` does more than you think. Visually it just appends a `)` character, but behind the scenes what happens is:

```
meaning.innerHTML = meaning.innerHTML + ')';
```

So, you're first converting the DOM to a string representation (HTML), then adding a `)` character, and finally have convert it back from HTML to the DOM. All elements the HTML represents are created again, and `meaning` is replaced by those new elements. So your old one is distroyed.

The simplest solution is to use `createTextNode`: http://jsfiddle.net/WcnCB/4/.

```
meaning.appendChild(document.createTextNode(")"));
```

Answer (score 4):

By writing `innerHTML += ...` you are overwriting the previous HTML and destroying every reference to it - including the `actual_button` variable.

Why are you using `innerHTML += ...` anyway? You should be doing:

```
meaning.appendChild(document.createTextNode("(Something"));
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do the greatest sin of all, that is `.innerHTML +=` (specifically `innerHTML` combined with `+=`, neither of them are bad alone), what happens is:

- Serialize the element's DOM subtree into a html string.
- Concatenate some stuff into that html string
- **Remove all elements from the target element**
- Parse the html resulted above into a new DOM subtree. This means all the elements are new.
- Append that into the target element

So given this, `actual_button` refers to a detached dom element. Not to the another img element created from parsing html.

Answer (score 1):

Works if you set the image ID and get it after changing innerHTML :

```
var meaning = document.getElementById('meaning');
meaning.innerHTML += 'Something ...';

var actual_button = document.createElement('img');
actual_button.id = 'actual_button';
actual_button.src = 'http://www.pawelbrewczynski.tk/images/add.png';
actual_button.className = 'add_word';

meaning.appendChild(actual_button);
meaning.innerHTML += " ... and another.";

var actual_button= document.getElementById('actual_button');
actual_button.src = 'http://www.pawelbrewczynski.tk/images/loading.gif';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j8yEG/1/